# jQueryUI's draggable clash with dragToSelect plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a case like this:

- In a wrapper div, I want some child divs to be draggable.
- In the **same** wrapper div, I want user to be able to perform dragToSelect.

Just FYI, I don't really need the select capability from dragToSelect, I use dragToSelect as visual presentation to get the dimension of a virtual square, but that's beyond the scope of my question.

[here is the jsfiddle If you want to see](http://jsfiddle.net/qrU6W/1/)

To do so, I use this plugin:

- [jQueryUI draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)
- [Andreas Lagerkvist's jQuery Drag to Select](http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/drag-to-select/)

Problem:

- dragToSelect went okay, not a problem here.
- draggable is actually also okay, but when doing so, dragToSelect is **also** activated!

is there any solution to toggle between two (draggable and dragToSelect)? Maybe stopping dragToSelect temporary when draggable is active? I don't mind If it needs a toggle button.

thx!